# Calculate the value owned by each `node` in the hierarchical database in` MYSQL 8`

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a table in a hierarchical database.
Because the level of complexity is high enough for me,
so I try to make it more general in the following link:

[DBFIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/62VLnKipCbykpHa7ye85iD/1)

I've also created a hierarchy image as shown below.

[image: Tree]

The rules of the game that must be followed are,

1. Only `nodes` that do not have a `child` or `leaf-node` can hold a value.
2. Each `level` will be assigned a `value` to a sub category line.

[image: Tree Value]

The results of the `query` above, can be seen in the `link` included above.
But the results we want to achieve are as follows.

```
+------+-----------+------+-------------------------+-----------------------+-------+------------+
| id   | parent_id | lvl  | name                    | path                  | value | rollup     |
+------+-----------+------+-------------------------+-----------------------+-------+------------+
|    1 |      NULL |    0 | A                       | A                     |       | Root       |
|    2 |         1 |    1 |   B                     | A > B                 |       | Category 1 |
|    3 |         2 |    2 |     C                   | A > B > C             |       | Category 2 |
|    4 |         3 |    3 |       D                 | A > B > C > D         |       | Category 3 |
|    5 |         4 |    4 |         E               | A > B > C > D > E     |    50 | Category 4 |
|    6 |         4 |    4 |         F               | A > B > C > D > F     |    50 | Category 4 |
|    7 |         4 |    4 |         G               | A > B > C > D > G     |    50 | Category 4 |
|      |         8 |    4 |       TOTAL D (E+F+G)   |                       |   150 |            |
|    8 |         3 |    3 |       H                 | A > B > C > H         |       | Category 3 |
|    9 |         8 |    4 |         I               | A > B > C > H > I     |    30 | Category 4 |
|   10 |         8 |    4 |         J               | A > B > C > H > J     |    40 | Category 4 |
|      |         8 |    4 |       TOTAL H (I+J)     |                       |    70 |            |
|      |         2 |    2 |     TOTAL C (D+H)       |                       |   220 |            |
|   11 |         2 |    2 |     K                   | A > B > K             |       | Category 2 |
|   12 |        11 |    3 |       L                 | A > B > K > L         |       | Category 3 |
|   13 |        12 |    4 |         M               | A > B > K > L > M     |     0 | Category 4 |
|   14 |        13 |    5 |           N             | A > B > K > L > M > N |     2 | Category 5 |
|   15 |        13 |    5 |           O             | A > B > K > L > M > O |     4 | Category 5 |
|   18 |        16 |    5 |         TOTAL M (N+O)   |                       |     6 |            |
|   16 |        12 |    4 |         P               | A > B > K > L > P     |       | Category 4 |
|   17 |        16 |    5 |           Q             | A > B > K > L > P > Q |    32 | Category 5 |
|   18 |        16 |    5 |           R             | A > B > K > L > P > R |    16 | Category 5 |
|      |        16 |    5 |         TOTAL P (Q+R)   |                       |    48 |            |
|      |        16 |    5 |       TOTAL L (M+P)     |                       |    54 |            |
|      |        16 |    5 |      TOTAL K (L)        |                       |    54 |            |
|      |         1 |    1 |   TOTAL B (C+K)         |                       |   274 |            |
|   19 |         1 |    1 |   S                     | A > S                 |       | Category 1 |
|   20 |        19 |    2 |     T                   | A > S > T             |       | Category 2 |
|   21 |        20 |    3 |       U                 | A > S > T > U         |     1 | Category 3 |
|   22 |        20 |    3 |       V                 | A > S > T > V         |     4 | Category 3 |
|   23 |        20 |    3 |       W                 | A > S > T > W         |     0 | Category 3 |
|      |        20 |    3 |     TOTAL T (U+V+W)     |                       |     5 |            |
|   24 |        19 |    2 |     X                   | A > S > X             |       | Category 2 |
|   25 |        24 |    3 |       Y                 | A > S > X > Y         |     3 | Category 3 |
|   26 |        24 |    3 |       Z                 | A > S > X > Z         |    14 | Category 3 |
|      |        24 |    3 |     TOTAL X (Y+Z)       |                       |    17 |            |
|      |        24 |    3 |   TOTAL S (T+X)         |                       |    22 |            |
|      |      NULL |    0 | TOTAL A (B+S)           |                       |   296 |            |
+------+-----------+------+-------------------------+-----------------------+-------+------------+
```

I have tried it with `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP`, but because this table is hierarchical, the results are not as expected.

How to selecting those data with ordered as we need, with total as subtotal each level.
So far, the query is :

```
WITH RECURSIVE adjacency_list_path (id, parent_id, lvl, name, path, value) AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id, 0 lvl, name, name as path, adjacency_list.`value`
    FROM adjacency_list
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.id, c.parent_id, (cp.lvl + 1), CONCAT(REPEAT("   " , (cp.lvl + 1)), c.name), CONCAT(cp.path, ' > ', c.name), c.`value`
    FROM adjacency_list_path AS cp
             JOIN adjacency_list AS c
                  ON cp.id = c.parent_id
)
SELECT id, parent_id, lvl, name, path, value
FROM adjacency_list_path
ORDER BY path;
```

Comment: i don't see a question anywhere?

Comment: How to selecting those data with ordered as we need.

Comment: Still stuck with no result

Comment: it is actually quite compölicated, it will need someone a lot of time, do you have a gui where you can run code in a loop, basically you must now identify nodes with values the knot on every level, i belive that will take too much effort to do that in sql.

Comment: A lot of energy to solved this problem by my self. Let me try in PHP 7.4